# Sum Report Items in ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a textbox in my report which should display the sum of another textbox. When I use the expression:
=SUM(ReportItems!TimeInMinutes.Value) and run the report, I get the following error:

[image]

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, you can either put the textbox containing the aggregate in the page header or footer (as it says in the error), or you can use the dataset's field value instead.

```
=SUM(Fields!TimeInMinutes.Value, "myDataSetNameHere")
```

You must include the quotes around the dataset name and it is case sensitive.

Notes:

1. If you use `ReportItems`, it will sum the report items on that page only, this may be what you want, I'm not sure.
2. If you use the `Fields` option, it will sum with in the scope defined. In this example, using the dataset name, it will sum the values for the entire dataset.
3. If you want to use `Fields` but only sum what is on the page then you will need a row group defined that controls the page breaks (you may have one already) in this case you use the row group's name as the scope e.g. `=SUM(Fields!TimeInMinutes.Value, "myRowGroupName")`

If this does not help, please edit your question and add more info about what you want to sum up, include screen shots of the report design and any groups you have defined. Sample data is always useful too with the expected output based on hat sample data.